# Package works in /usr/local/lib but does not at /usr/lib

Tags: python, package

When I install a package 'python-brick-cinderclient-ext' from sources it works. But when I try to install it from .deb package that I've built, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brick_cinderclient_ext/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
'brick-python-cinderclient-ext').version_string()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 457, in version_string
return self.semantic_version().brief_string()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 452, in semantic_version
self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 439, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 668, in get_version
raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

But when I've move the code in the same location that it installs with `python setup.py install` *(from the **/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/** to **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/**)* then it worked fine! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the wrong name for *pbr.version* module. There is **brick-python-cinderclient-ext** instead of **python-brick-cinderclient-ext** in the __init__.py file. So, it's a reason why pbr could not get the version of this package -> **It's just could not find the version of such package in the egg.info**. I've fixed it with the patch for __init__.py file with renaming *brick-python-cinderclient-ext* to *python-brick-cinderclient-ext*.